# Imaplib not deleting emails

Tags: python, imaplib

I need to make to delete all emails from mail server and I have made some code that handles that. But it doesn't work I have tried everything and still not delete it from mail server.

So I need to ask If somebody know what I missing to code so it deletes emails on Plesk/kolab mail system.

My code is

```
from lib.Enums.status import Status


class Imap:
    mailserver = None
    port = 993

    _conn = ''

    def __init__(self, mailserver=None, port=993):
        self.mailserver = mailserver
        self.port = port


    def connect(self):
        if self.mailserver is not None:
            try:
                self._conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.mailserver, self.port)
                return self
            except imaplib.IMAP4 as e:
                # TODO: make log
                return e.error

        return None

    # Login
    def login(self, username=None, password=None):
        if username is not None and password is not None:
            try:
                self._conn.login(username, password)
                return self
            except imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.error as e:
                # TODO: make log
                return Status.FAIL


    def get_all_message_new(self):
        return self._conn.search(None, "ALL")

    def delete_message(self, mail):
        # mark the mail as deleted
        return self._conn.store(mail, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')

    # Delete permanently message
    def delete_permanently(self):
        self._conn.expunge()
```

EmailHandler:

```
def delete_emails(self, info_obj):

        # Mailserver transfer from
        mail_server = Imap(info_obj.url).connect()
        mail_server.login(info_obj.username, info_obj.password)

        # Get folder list from mail server
        directories = mail_server.get_directories()

        status, data = mail_server.select('INBOX')

        typ, msg_ids = mail_server.get_all_message_new()

        for mail in msg_ids[0].decode().split():
            # mark the mail as deleted
            mov, data = mail_server.delete_message(mail)
            print(data)

        mail_server.delete_permanently()
        mail_server.close()
        mail_server.logout()

        return Status.SUCCESS
```

I receive response
[OK, [None]]

Do anybody have idea what is missing and I found lot of solutions but it's most working for Gmail. I want to handle all mail servers as possible.

Comment: GMail is special that marking a message as \Deleted only removes that label from the Inbox (or current mailbox), effectively archiving it.  If you wish to delete it,, you need to `move` it to the Trash folder.  Then if you want to delete it permanently, you need to switch to the Trash folder and mark it \Deleted and expunge it from there.

Comment: I have tried this also copy a message to another folder and not helped. 
`return self._conn.uid('COPY', msg_uid, destination)` But it's not GMail I want to delete mails from it's from shared hosting PLESK.

Comment: At first glance, the code looks okay; you’re not making the mistakes of mixing UIDs and Sequences; you’re not expunging until you’re done (which moves sequences…), so it looks okay.  By specification this appears to be correct.  You could turn on imaplib debugging to see the commands you’re sending; posting that log may help us.

Comment: okay I have made debugging and can see that my inbox is read only permissions. Have I right that's why expunge is not allowed to delete emails?
Debug log file to long for this answered box I have post below so you can check it.

Comment: Your log indicates you used ‘EXAMINE’ rather than ‘SELECT’; so your code does not match.  EXAMINE specifically asks for a read-only mailbox, you can not change flags or expunge messages.

Comment: Make sure you’re using https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.select without the readonly flag.

Comment: Thanks man you have totally right i forgot that I have added readonly on select. When I put false it was working thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this issue is to make false for readonly instead of true

```
   # Get all raw messages from current directory
def select(self, dir=None,readonly=False):
    if dir is not None:
        return self._conn.select(dir, readonly)
```